# Sed substitution on capture group

Tags: string, bash, sed

I would like to create a bash function which behaves in the following way:

- If passed a string with no flags, add the second argument as flags
- If passed any flag which is in the second argument, keep it in the flags.
- If passed any flag with the letter `c` or `d`, we remove it.
- If there is any other character in the flag, we want to keep those and append the second argument as flags.

For example:

```sh
my_func 'cmd pattern' 'ab' #=> cmd -ab pattern
my_func 'cmd -a pattern' 'ab' #=> cmd -ab pattern
my_func 'cmd -ac pattern' 'ab' #=> cmd -ab pattern
my_func 'cmd -aef pattern' 'ab' #=> cmd -efab pattern
my_func 'cmd -deaf pattern' 'ab' #=> cmd -efab pattern
```

This is what I have tried:

```sh
function my_func() {
  echo $1 |
  # case with no flags
  sed "/^cmd [^-]/s/^cmd \(.*$\)/cmd -$2 \1/" |
  # case with flags in $2 or `a` or `b`
  sed "/^cmd -[$2ab]+ /s/^cmd -[$2ab] \(.*$\)/cmd -$2 \1/" |
  # case with other flags
  sed ...
}
```

I'm struggling with the last one. I'm not sure if it's possible, but would love to know if it is.

It would somehow capture the flags (`cmd -\([a-z]\)`),

then remove `abcd` from the capture group (`sed 's/[abcd]//g'` on the group)

then take that value and append `ab` in the output.

It would also be cool to know if there is a nicer implementation using something other than `sed`

Comment: do you know about the `case ..... esac` syntax in the shell? I would think what you want could be done more easily with that, and with fewer/no external process calls (i.e. `sed`). AND I don't think `-[$2ab]+` will work the way you need it to, or did you test that thoroughly? Good luck.

Comment: I would also consider whether using `getopts` might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, sed probably isn't needed.

Here's a pure bash version:

```
my_func(){
    local cmd arg1 rest flags

    if [[ $2 =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
        echo 1>&2 "bad character in arg2"
        exit 1
    fi

    read -r cmd arg1 rest <<< $1

    if [[ $arg1 =~ ^[^-] ]]; then
        # no flags
        echo "$cmd -$2 $arg1${rest:+ $rest}"
    else
        # have flags

        # strip unwanted/duplicates and append new
        eval 'flags=${arg1//[cd'$2']/}$2'

        # append new flags and return
        echo "$cmd $flags $rest"
    fi
}
```

`eval` is dangerous if passed untrusted data (as is your `sed` using `$2` unchecked) - always do a sanity check - I've assumed here that flags must be alphanumerics.

---

If you want to use sed, this should work (same caveat about sanity-checking `$2`:

```
my_func(){
    sed <<< $1 '
        /^\([^ ][^ ]*\) \([^-]\)/ { # no flags
            s//\1 -'$2' \2/;
            q;
         }
        /^[^ ][^ ]* -\([^ ]*\) .*/ { # has flags
            h;
            s//\1/;
            s/[cd'$2']//g;
            G;
            s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\([^ ][^ ]* -\)[^ ]*\( .*\)/\2\1'$2'\3/;
            q;
        }
        {
            s/.*/#ERROR: malformed input/;
            q;
        }
    '
}
```